# protected inheritance error

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class base 
{
protected:
    int a;

public:
    base(int i)
    {
        a=i;
    }
};

class derived :protected base
{
public:
    derived(){}

    void show()
    {
        cout<<a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    base obj(2);
    derived obj1;
    obj1.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this program giving error as In constructor `derived::derived()`:

> error: no matching function for call to `base::base()`

Please explain. As i have read in stackoverflow that in case of inheriting as protected, protected members of base class became protected member of derived class. If I am wrong then please share a good link to clear my misconception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you define a constructor for any class, the compiler does not generate the default constructor for that class.

You define the parameterized constructor(`base(int i)`) for `base` and hence the compiler does not generate the no argument constructor for `base`.

**Resolution:**
You will need to define a constructor taking no arguments for `base` yourself.
Add this to your `base` class:

```
base():a(0)
{

}
```

EDIT:

> Is it needed to define default constructor to every class? Or is it necessary to have the constructor that matches the derived type also present in base type?

The answer to both is **NO**.

The purpose of constructors in C++ is to initialize the member variables of the class inside the constructor. As you understand the compiler generates the default constructor(constructor which takes no arguments) for every class.

But there is a catch, If you yourself define (any)constructor(one with parameters or without) for your class, the compiler does not generate the default constructor for that anymore. The compiler reasoning here is *"Huh, this user writes a constrcutor for his class himself, so probably he needs to do something special in the constructor which I cannot do or understand"*, armed with this reasoning the compiler just does not generate the default no argument constructor anymore.

Your code above and you assume the presence of the default no argument constructor(When `derived` class object is created). But since you already defined one constructor for your `base` class the compiler has applied its reasoning and now it refuses to generate any default argument constructor for your `base` class. Thus the absence of the no argument constructor in the `base` class results in the compiler error.

Comment: why is it needed?I have creted the no argument constructor for derived.please explain.

Comment: is it needed to define default constructor to every class?Or is it necessary to have the constructor that matches the derived type also present in base type.Sorry if I am erong.Please help.Or

Comment: If you define a constructor that accepts arguments, the compiler will not generate the default constructor. This is how C++ works. If you need to have a constructor that accepts arguments and created a derived class that accepts no arguments, what value will `base::a` be by default? You need to define that with the default constructor.

Comment: @gautamkumar: I updated the answer to explain it better & hth.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement an empty constructor in `base` or invoke the defined `base(int)` constructor explicitly from `derived` c-tor. Without it, when `derived` c'tor is activated, 
it is trying to invoke `base()` [empty c'tor], and it does not exist, and you get your error.

Answer (score 2):

You must give a value to the base constructor:

```
class Derived : protected base
{
public:
     Derived() : base(0)
     {

     }
};
```

Depending on your implementation, give the value to the `base` constructor. However, you may want the `Derived` constructor to take also `int` as an argument, and then pass it to the `base` one.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined a default constructor for `Base`..

When you instantiate an instance of `Derived`, it will call the `Derived()` constructor, which will in turn try to call the `Base()` default constructur which doesn't exist as you haven't defined it.

You can either declare an empty constructor for base `Base::Base()` or call the existing one as below:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class base 
{

protected:
    int a;

public:
    base(int i)
    {
        a=i;
    }
};

class derived :protected base
{
    derived(): Base(123) {}  --this will call the Base(int i) constructor)

    void show()
    {
        cout<<a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    base obj(2);
    derived obj1;
    obj1.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning both options: Either create a default ctor in base or call the existing Base(int) from derived()!